# Playing sound C++ linux aplay : device or resource busy

Tags: c++, linux, asynchronous, audio

Im trying to play a small audio (.wav) file whenever a face is detected in a camera using opencv in C++ (**LINUX**).

```
    #include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
    
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;
    
    /** Global variables */
    String faceCascadePath;
    CascadeClassifier faceCascade;
    
    void detectFaceOpenCVHaar(CascadeClassifier faceCascade, Mat &frameOpenCVHaar, int inHeight=300, int inWidth=0)
    {
        int frameHeight = frameOpenCVHaar.rows;
        int frameWidth = frameOpenCVHaar.cols;
        if (!inWidth)
            inWidth = (int)((frameWidth / (float)frameHeight) * inHeight);
    
        float scaleHeight = frameHeight / (float)inHeight;
        float scaleWidth = frameWidth / (float)inWidth;
    
        Mat frameOpenCVHaarSmall, frameGray;
        resize(frameOpenCVHaar, frameOpenCVHaarSmall, Size(inWidth, inHeight));
        cvtColor(frameOpenCVHaarSmall, frameGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    
        std::vector<Rect> faces;
        faceCascade.detectMultiScale(frameGray, faces);
    
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
        {
          int x1 = (int)(faces[i].x * scaleWidth);
          int y1 = (int)(faces[i].y * scaleHeight);
          int x2 = (int)((faces[i].x + faces[i].width) * scaleWidth);
          int y2 = (int)((faces[i].y + faces[i].height) * scaleHeight);
          rectangle(frameOpenCVHaar, Point(x1, y1), Point(x2, y2), Scalar(0,255,0), (int)(frameHeight/150.0), 4);
         
   //// ==== AUDIO PLAY CODE BEGINS ======= ////
          string str1 = "aplay ";
          str1 = str1 + " out.wav" + " & ";
          const char *command = str1.c_str();
          system(command);
   //// ==== AUDIO CODE ENDS ======== /////
    
        }
    }
    
    
    int main( int argc, const char** argv )
    {
        faceCascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml";
        if(!faceCascade.load(faceCascadePath))
        {
            printf("--(!)Error loading face cascade\n");
            return -1;
        }
    
        VideoCapture source;
        if (argc == 1)
            source.open(0, CAP_V4L);
        else
            source.open(argv[1]);  Mat frame;
    
        double tt_opencvHaar = 0;
        double fpsOpencvHaar = 0;
    
        while (true)
        {
            source >> frame;
            if (frame.empty())
                break;
    
            double t = cv::getTickCount();
            detectFaceOpenCVHaar(faceCascade, frame);
            tt_opencvHaar = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t)/cv::getTickFrequency();
            fpsOpencvHaar = 1/tt_opencvHaar;
             
            putText(frame, format("OpenCV HAAR ; FPS = %.2f",fpsOpencvHaar), Point(10, 50), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.3, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 4);
    
            imshow("OpenCV - HAAR Face Detection", frame);
    
            int k = waitKey(5);
            if(k == 27)
            {
                destroyAllWindows();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now whats happening is that whenever a person stays longer in front of the camera, the camera keeps detecting face and sound file keeps trying to play but due to device already busy playing the sound, its giving error on console. Ofcourse I can hear the alarm, but how to stop simultaneous playing of alarm when an alarm is already playing or how to make them wait before the sound file finishes.
This constant call to sound file play is slowing down the code also. How to fix this error and optimize the audio play so that it doesnt stress the cpu ?

Error :-

```
Playing WAVE 'out.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
Playing WAVE 'out.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo

aplay : audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

**What I need help with** : Make sound play smooth and non taxing on CPU. Face detection is occuring at approx 30fps, hence for each of the frame sound is trying to play which isnt possible and maybe its slowing down the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this code:

```
if (face_recognized) {
string str1= "aplay" ;
str1 = str1 + "-Dhw:0,3 alarm.wav" + " & ";
const char *command = str1.c_str();
system(command)

while (face_recognized)
{
face_recognized = check_if_face_is_recognised(); // replace with function that checks if face is recognised
}
}
```

Not sure if this will work because I don't have linux but I hope it is useful.

Comment: SOrry but my issue is different. I want the audio file to wait before another one starts playing

Comment: @Monishayadav ok didn't think my code would work! I tried to make it wait until the face was no longer recognised. Sorry it didn't work!