# How to convert the system call to fork in C++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, fork

This is the code for playing sound file in C++ linux code

```
 string str1 = "aplay ";
 str1 = str1 + " out.wav" + " & ";
 const char *command = str1.c_str();
 system(command);
```

** Entire code is available here : [Playing sound C++ linux aplay : device or resource busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68050326/playing-sound-c-linux-aplay-device-or-resource-busy)

I just want to know how to play this in a fork() as I read that system call is too taxing on cpu, which ofcourse is in my case.
Please help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the code you provided.

Comment: I don't imagine `fork` will be significantly faster than `system`, the main cost is in launching a new process

Comment: `system` is a combination of `fork` and `exec`. It is not "too taxing on cpu", but it does block until the program has finished.

Comment: What you need to do is to avoid playing 30 sound files per second. This is going to be a problem regardless of how you launch `aplay`. Look for some library for playing sounds instead of delegating to a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

`fork` will make a copy of your process, so you can easily write:

```
// fork the current process: beyond this point, you will have 2 process
int ret = fork();
if (ret == 0) {
   // in child: execute the long command
   system("aplay out.wav");
   // exit the child process
   exit(0);
}

// child process will not go here

if (ret < 0) {
    perror("fork");
}
```

---

After, you should know that `system` will do for you `fork` + `exec` + `wait`. Since you don't want your parent process to wait the child, you can write:

```
// fork the current process: beyond this point, you will have 2 process
int ret = fork();
if (ret == 0) {
   // in child: execute the long command
   char program[] = "/usr/bin/aplay";
   char *args[] = {"/usr/bin/aplay", "out.wav" };
   ret = execv(program, args); 

  // this point will be reach only if `exec` fails
  // so if we reach this point, we've got an error.
  perror("execv");

  exit(0);
}

// child process will not go here

if (ret < 0) {
    perror("fork");
}
```

Comment: This is now a double-fork. You first fork a child process, which then forks `aplay`. Doing twice the work is not a CPU optimization at all! You could call `execl` instead of `system`. This is just as efficient as the original `system` call, so it still fails to answer the question, but it's also more verbose and failure-prone.